# Finding the maximum point in a linear regression model

Tags: regression, optimization, scikit-learn

I have a set of data points that I used to train a linear model (with polynomial interpolation as described [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html).

In my understanding, the linear model can be described as a response function approximating the function underlying the data points.

My question is now: How can I find the optimum (maximum) point of that response surface / linear model? I
In my example code I'd expect to get x=2.93 as a result.

Since the polynomial interpolation should be an analytical function, I'd expect analytical methods of finding the optimum (= root of the derivative). But I couldn't find anything implemented in scikit-learn.
Alternatively, any hints on how to apply numerical algorithms to find the maximum would be appreciated as well.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import SplineTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Fun(x):
       return 1*np.sin(0.5*x)+0.2*np.sin(7*x)

# data generation
x_plot = np.linspace(0,6.28,300)
x_train = np.linspace(0.2,6,17)

y_train = Fun(x_train)
y_plot = Fun(x_plot)

# create 2D-array versions of these arrays to feed to transformers
X_train = x_train[:, np.newaxis]
X_plot = x_plot[:, np.newaxis]

y_predictions=list()
labels = list()
# spline fits
model = make_pipeline(SplineTransformer(n_knots=20, degree=3,extrapolation='linear'), Ridge(alpha=1e-3))
model.fit(X_train,y_train)

y_predictions.append(model.predict(X_plot))
labels.append('spline fitting')

# plotting
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

#plot original function
ax.plot(x_plot,y_plot, 'k',label='original data')

# plot training points
ax.plot(x_train,y_train,'xk',label='training points')

#plot fits
for i in range(len(y_predictions)):
       ax.plot(x_plot,y_predictions[i],':',label=labels[i])

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is often called *Response Surface Modellling*,  [many posts with answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=response+surface++answers%3A1)

Comment: Hi kjetil, I had a look at your links - many posts, but I couldn't find a single one that adresses the problem of how to find the actual maximum of the response surface with the help of python libraries. Can you point me to a specific one?

Comment: How to solve with Python libraries, is, strictly speaking, off-topic here (and I do not use Python). But there must be some library for numerical optimization? Then, define your fitted model function, *as a function of the covariates* with betas fixed at the estimates, as the criterion function to optimize (with apropriate boundaries on the x's?

Comment: Might this [stackoverflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34293045/how-to-extract-derivative-from-a-polynomial-fit) help?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, yes there are python libraries for numircal optimization and I ended up using 'scipy.optimize.minimize' with the fitted model function as function to minimize. So problem solven, however with a numeric / iterative approach. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @rickhg12hs, that thread you posted is somewhat going into the direction of my original plan to do more of a anlythical aproch by finding the roots of the derivative. However the numeric approach worked quite well so I didn't dive into this any further, but thanks anyway.